Share AMD GPU from Windows (Host) to Ubuntu (Guest)
Can't seem to find a solution for this anywhere.
I've got a Windows Host with an AMD GPU (Radeon 6800 XT).
There's software I need to run that requires an AMD GPU but it's only available in Linux.
I don't want to lose the GPU on my Windows Host, but rather share it so the AMD GPU is also available in the Ubuntu VM. How can I accomplish this? And what VM software should I use?

To split one GPU among multiple users (host, VMs), you need GPU virtualization. I doubt your card can do that. Just dual-boot instead and save yourself the trouble.

As @DanielB states, you can test the software under VM, and under Linux booted from USB, such as Ubuntu Live, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started . Compare performance, and see which, if either, better meet your needs.

Wesley probably would work in this situation
